# Descargar multiples archivos con AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

Tengo que descargar diferentes audios en una carpeta interna en Android, leo un archivo xml desde una url, tengo el siguiente código:

```
              List<Audio> canciones = new ArrayList<>();
              canciones = parserxml.parsear(result);
              List<Audio> audios_xml = writeXMLFile(canciones); //Creo un XML interno con algunos datos más.

              for (Audio url : canciones) {

                  new  GetAudioFromServer().execute(url.getUrl_audio(),url.getNombre(), String.valueOf(canciones.indexOf(url)));
              }

                listFragmentListener.cargar(audios_xml);
```

Con este código me descarga todos los audios que quiero en la carpeta correcta pero llamo al método GetAudioFromServer(), tantas veces como canciones existan en el XML desde la url. 
El método GetAudioFromServer es el siguiente:

```
  class GetAudioFromServer extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    HttpHandler conexion;
    File outputFile = null;
    File cancion  = null;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        verifyStoragePermissions(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Descargando audio..."+ url[1]+".mp3");
        pDialog.setTitle("Descargando");

        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setMax(100);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                cancel(true);
            }
        });

        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
      //  super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        pDialog.setMessage("Descargando audio..."+ url[1]+".mp3");
        pDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
        listFragmentListener.cambios();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {


            conexion = new HttpHandler();

                try {

                    File mFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Directorio_interno");
                    if (!mFolder.exists()) {
                        boolean b = mFolder.mkdirs();

                    }
                    cancion = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Directorio_Interno"));
                    outputFile = new File(cancion, url[1] + ".mp3");

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                    InputStream is = conexion.CallServer(url[0]);
                    int fileLength = conexion.getFileLength();

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int count = -1;
                    long total = 0;
                    while ((count = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));

                        fos.write(buffer, 0, count);

                        if (isCancelled()) {
                            outputFile.delete();
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                    is.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error" + e);
                }

            return url[2];

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (outputFile != null){
            pDialog.setMessage("Descargando..");


            listFragmentListener.cambios();
            pDialog.dismiss();
        } else {
            pDialog.setMessage("Fallo al descargar");
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    pDialog.setMessage("volviendo a descargar");
                }
            },3000);
        }

        if (result.equals("ok")){

        }
        listFragmentListener.cambios();


    }


}
```

El problema que tengo es que lanza tantos ProgressDialog como canciones existen en el xml, y es lógico ya que llamo tantas veces al GetAudioFromServer dentro del loop indicado anteriormente, ¿Cómo sería la manera más eficiente de realizar esto y que aparezca un sólo progressdialog indicando el total de canciones y el porcentaje de descarga? Muchas Gracias

Comment: Te sugeriría hacer que tu clase escriba los estados (mensajes) en una variable externa y que esa misma variable sea monitoreada (observada) por otro método que al detectar los cambios, o bien leer el contenido cada `n` segundos, vaya actualizando el contenido del `progressdialog`. Puedes mirar este video tutorial en [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MoW3Qna2tiU), que está en portugués pero se entiende.

Comment: En lugar de enviar un url cada vez que llamas el AsyncTask, modifica para que puedas enviar un array del url´s.

Comment: Gracias, @Jorgesys ¿podrías poner un ejemplo? Tengo todos los datos en un List<Audio> canciones = new ArrayList<>(); donde tiene varios campos entre ellos la url de descarga.